# Ошибочно отклонённая правка

Tags: обсуждение, правки, отклонённые-правки

[Правка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/423046) [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1056404/183305) отклонена как

> Правка не соответствует исходному содержанию сообщения. Даже правки,
>   которые призваны изменить сообщение в корне, должны быть выполнены с
>   соблюдением идей автора сообщения.

Автор вопроса добавил ответ (который ответом не является), в котором добавил уточняющую информацию о вопросе. Я хотел перенести эту информацию в вопрос, где ей и место.

Считаю, что отклонение правки произошло по недосмотру, так как эта доп информация и была предоставлена самим автором, что и было указано в комментарии к правке.

Разве эта правка не должна была быть одобрена?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Должна быть принята.

Тем не менее, все мы люди — иногда ошибаемся; думаю, это тот самый, нечастый случай.

Перенёс ответ в тело вопроса.

Comment: в очереди проверок еще можно не редко ткнуть не туда, жаль, что отменить никак